# pandas replace 0s with a value returned by a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of zeros in my pandas dataframe. I'd like to replace them with a value returned by a function. I am doing something similar using `fillna`. Here's a simplified version of my code for reproducibility:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def replace(x):
    v = x * 2
    return v

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,np.nan,0],
                   'col2': [1,2,3]
                 })

df['col1'].replace(0, value returned by replace function)
```

Ideally, I'd like use lambda to do this. Here's how I am doing this for NaNs:

```
df['col1'].fillna(df.apply(lambda x: replace(x.col2), axis=1), inplace=True)
```

Comment: I think your code might be oversimplified. What are you trying to do? Something like `df.loc[df['col1'].eq(0), 'col1'] = df.loc[df['col1'].eq(0), 'col2'].apply(replace)`? (Which in this case can be `df.loc[df['col1'].eq(0), 'col1'] = df.loc[df['col1'].eq(0), 'col2'] * 2` but I've shown the apply since this is simplified code)

Comment: @HenryEcker Basically, replace all 0s in `col1` by value returned by `replace` function which takes `col2` value as argument.

Answer (score 1):

`apply` can take the lambda function that you wish to use:

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col2']*2 if x['col1'] == 0 else x['col1'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to replace a specific value in a DataFrame with that returned by a simple function, you can use [pd.DataFrame.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html).

To replace all 0s in a DataFrame with the result of `replace()`:

```
new_df = df.where( df != 0, replace( df ) )
```

Wherever the condition is true (in this case, df is not equal to 0), the function keeps the original value, and wherever the condition is false (in this case, df is equal to 0), the function returns the result of `replace()`.

The where() function can also be applied to an individual series. To use your function:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].where( df["col1"] != 0, replace( df["col1"] ) )
```

To replace values of `col2` with `replace()` where `col1` is equal to zero:

```
df["col2"] = df["col2"].where( df["col1"] != 0, replace( df["col2"] ) )
```

Comment: replace takes `col2` as argument. Where is that in the code? Were you able to run this successfully on the example provided?

Comment: Added how you would use where() on a series and a note that for this example the input and desired output are the same.

Comment: `col2` value is 3 for when `col1` is 0, so `3` is passed to the function which returns `6`. How is desired input = output?

Comment: I understood your question as replacing zero values with replace(x). To change col2 values with replace(x) where col1 is equal to 0, use `df["col2"] = df["col2"].where( df["col1"] != 0, replace( df["col2"] ) )`